# Propel cannot delete due to Integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, propel

I'm running on Propel 1.6.9 and the previous developer recently updated the files since I still have some trouble generating the proper files on my laptop. All went well except for one problem while trying to delete something.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db000_app/file_meta`, CONSTRAINT `file_meta_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`case_id`) REFERENCES `agency_costs` (`id`))' in /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/domain/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/connection/DebugPDOStatement.php:90 

Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/domain/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/connection/DebugPDOStatement.php(90): PDOStatement->execute(NULL) 
#1 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/domain/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/util/BasePeer.php(145): DebugPDOStatement->execute() 
#2 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/domain/vendor/propel/propel1/build/classes/onterechtbetaald/om/BaseAgencyCostsPeer.php(1085): BasePeer::doDelete(Object(AgencyCostsQuery), Object(DebugPDO)) 
#3 [internal function]: BaseAgencyCo in /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/domain/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/util/BasePeer.php on line 149
```

The code calling the delete function:

```
$case = AgencyCostsQuery::create()->findPk($_POST["DeleteId"]);

if ($case !== null)
{
  $case->deleteFiles();
  $case->delete();
}
```

As said this worked just fine before the files were updated. The database has been changed: two columns have been added to agency_costs.

Any ideas on how to overcome this error?

Comment: Not sure what exactly the problem coul be, but it looks like some parent record is being deleted while there are child rows being deleted.

Maybe check your relationships, one of them is being violated

Comment: I think so as well but the delete function of Propel is supposed to take care of the relations. There was no extra table added, just two new columns to the table. Relations therefore haven't been altered.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem was caused by the definition of the constraint in the database.
The constraint was set to restrict on delete and on update.
Changing this to cascade solved my problem.

Comment: For those who are facing the same problem: check foreign-keys topic http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/schema.html#foreign-key-element you need to set onUpdate= "cascade", which means those child items will also be deleted.